# What is a Good Alternative to the Word "Novel" in Engineering Publications?

Tags: publications, thesis, writing-style, engineering

When writing papers for engineering conferences and journals, it is important to highlight how one's work is novel/new.

I often find myself repeating the word "novel" is sentences such as:

> The novel control algorithm presented here....

but I feel this is quite tedious if repeated often. I sometimes use phrases such as

> This work extends the state-of-the-art by...

but don't particularily like the sound of that either. I've looked in several thesauruses, and we often debate this question at the coffee table in our research lab, but we have not yet come up with many compelling alternatives.
Are there any other suggestions for phrasing ways in which my work is "new"?

Comment: Find a thesaurus, maybe online. You will find lots of synonyms. In the old days, writers kept a printed one at their elbow along with their dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have looked in thesauruses on many occasions but not found any satisfying alternatives. By askiung the question here, I was hoping to get input from people who have also had this issue and perhaps come up with nice expressions.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe read Apple or Microsoft product announcements. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps the answer is in your question. "important to highlight HOW one's work is novel"... maybe don't focus on calling out that it is novel but focus on why it is novel. "Previous control algorithms suffer from X, this problem is attenuated by our algorithm which includes Y"